# Using generics over interface for swapping implementations in client code

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstraction

I'm attempting to create abstractions for messaging queues (a la RabbitMQ), but I've ran into a problem.

Assume I have the following:

```cs
interface IMessagingQueue { }

interface IMessagingExchange
{
    Bind(IMessagingQueue queue);
}

class RabbitQueue : IMessagingQueue { }

class RabbitExchange : IMessagingExchange
{
    // FIX
    Bind(IMessagingQueue queue) { }
}

class InMemoryQueue : IMessagingQueue {  }
```

This works well because the client is not tied to a specific implementation,. Example:

```cs
class Client
{
    public Client(IMessagingExchange exchange) { }
}
```

However, a problem comes into play where I marked `// FIX`.

In this example, an `InMemoryQueue` could be passed to a `RabbitExchange` (via `Bind`), which doesn't make sense architecturally.

Of course, I could introduce generics a la:

```cs
interface IMessagingExchange<TQueue> where TQueue : IMessagingQueue
{
    Bind(TQueue queue);
}
```

However, now the client code is tied to an implementation due to the introduction of a generic:

```cs
class RabbitExchange : IMessagingExchange<RabbitQueue> { }

class Worker
{
    public Worker(RabbitExchange exchange) { }
}
```

This does introduce compile-time safety, but sacrifices the ability to swap out implementations.

Am I overthinking this? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `which doesn't make sense architecturally.` Sounds like you found the problem. `InMemoryQueue` probably should implement a different interface then.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to swap implementations seamlessly, but you can't just accept any implementation, so here is something I have done in the past and has worked out pretty well:

Create two versions of the interface to be able to swap seamlessly without specifying types:

```
interface IMessagingExchange
{
    void Bind(IMessagingQueue queue);
}

interface IMessagingExchange<TQueue> : IMessagingExchange where TQueue : IMessagingQueue
{
    void Bind(TQueue queue);
}
```

Create an interface to identify a subset of queues that can be used with a particular exchange. In this case, we identify queues that can be used by the Rabbit Exchange:

```
interface IRabbitQueue : IMessagingQueue { }
```

The `RabbitQueue` class now implements this interface:

```
class RabbitQueue : IRabbitQueue { }
```

We add a base class to handle the type checking:

```
abstract class ExchangeBase<TQueue> : IMessagingExchange<TQueue>  where TQueue : class, IMessagingQueue
{
    public abstract void Bind(TQueue queue);

    public void Bind(IMessagingQueue queue)
    {
        var typedQueue = queue as TQueue;
        if (typedQueue == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"This exchange only supports queues that implement {typeof(TQueue).FullName}");
        Bind(typedQueue);
    }
}
```

Notice the base class implements the untyped version, does the type checking for you and forwards the request to the typed version, which is provided by the concrete class.

The `RabbitExchange` class now inherits from the base class and provides the binding logic:

```
class RabbitExchange : ExchangeBase<IRabbitQueue>
{
    public override void Bind(IRabbitQueue queue)
    {

    }
}
```

**Execution:**

```
//Using untyped versions
IMessagingExchange exchange = new RabbitExchange();
IMessagingQueue queue = new RabbitQueue();

//This works fine
exchange.Bind(queue);

//Attempt to use the wrong queue
IMessagingQueue memoryQueue = new InMemoryQueue();
//This results in an error
exchange.Bind(memoryQueue);
```

> This exchange only supports queues that implement
>   SomeNameSpace.IRabbitQueue

```
//We use a typed exchange this time
var rabbitExchange = exchange as RabbitExchange;

//This works
rabbitExchange.Bind(queue);
//This is still allowed because of the untyped interface, but causes an error because type is still checked
rabbitExchange.Bind(memoryQueue);

//Use a typed queue this time
var rabbitQueue = queue as RabbitQueue;
//This skips the base class validation because it calls the typed method in the concrete class
rabbitExchange.Bind(rabbitQueue);
```